# Maven pom.xml file shows error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i cloned a maven project from git hub. But in the pom file it shows error.git hub project don't have any errors. Because it is working perfectly in another machine.And i'm not behind any proxy servers. I tried most of the sollutions in the stackoverflow. But i could not overcome from that issue.

**ERROR**

```
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.10 from http://
 repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted 
 until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer 
 artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.10 from/to central (http://
 repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/
 plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.10/maven-surefire-plugin-2.10.pom
```

[image]

**What i have done so far?**

- Right Click on Projec --> Maven -->update project. it doesn't work
- Run as maven install
- Delete Project and got a fresh copy again. same issue was there
- Set maven to out side maven folder
- Deleted all maven settings. re installed.
- Re installed fresh copy of eclipse and changed by workspace

Nothing works for me. Plz help me.....

Comment: try this on the command line : `mvn -U install` (<MAVEN_HOME>/bin must in your $PATH and you must run it in the root directory of your project). The -U option means : force dependencies update (i.e. the local repository cache shouldn't be used)

Comment: i using eclipse to build my project and used eclipse maven plugin

Comment: it is not working it shows error

Comment: If it's not a proxy issue, it might be a firewall issue. There is something which blocks you from downloading.

Comment: did you try my suggestion?

Comment: i tried your solution. But finally i found the reason. in git hub my collaborator pushed wrong dependency.

Comment: @Exbury please put an answer and mark question as "answered"

Answer (score 1):

Go to your local repo (usually it is under .m2), and search for org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin directory. You will find there a "placeholder" - try to delete this directory and try to re-build.

Then, I suggest to **build the project from command-line**, and not from any other tool such as eclipse, because all IDEs may faces issues, so first let's make sure the project compiles successfuly from command line, and only then we will try to solve IDEs issues.

In addition, @ben is correct - you can run `mvn -U clean install` to force maven to download a fresh copy.

Answer (score 0):

***try***

find ~/.m2  -name "*.lastUpdated" -exec grep -q "Could not transfer" {} \; -print -exec rm {} \;

Comment: Try to explain your answer a bit more so it is useful for future readers

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Maven nature and again enable Maven.

1. Right click the project => Maven => Disable Maven Nature
2. Right click the project => Configure => Convert to Maven Project

Try is this works.